# Ajax POST large base64 from mobible

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, base64

I have a Canvas where clients can sign a form in my web page. I am sending this base64 string through an AJAX POST to a NodeJs server and it works no mater how big is the file **if I run the process in my PC**. If the **signature is small** **it can be uploaded from a mobile device too**.

The problem is when I am in a mobile device and the base64 string is too long. There is no limit request in the server because large strings can be send when I am in a PC.

I've search everywhere for two days and I don't find why this large strings doesn't pass on a mobile device.

```
var canvasBase64 = data:image/png;base64,/9j/4SxvRXhpZgAASUkq...large string
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            imgBase64:canvasBase64,
        },
        url: '/nodejsroute',
        success: function(response){
        //success functions
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how but I found the answer after posting this question(I searched and tried everything for three days). If you have this same problem passing big data to express do this and it will work.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
  limit: '50mb',
  parameterLimit:50000

}));
```